# Key diagnostic features in diagnosing fit for non-gaussian GAM

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have run the below model

```
> supply.negbinom <- gam(NumberRequests ~ s(nMonth, bs = "cc", k = 12) + 
               s(nMonth, bs = "cc", k = 12, by = State) + 
               s(Time) + 
               s(Time, by = State)+
               State + Weight, 
             data = supply.pad, 
             family = nb(), 
             method = "REML", 
             knots = knots2,
             select = TRUE)
```

The model summary gives me a negative adjusted R squared value but a high percentage deviance explained.

```
> summary(supply.negbinom) 

Family: Negative Binomial(1.855) 
Link function: log 

Formula:
NumberRequests ~ s(nMonth, bs = "cc", k = 12) + s(nMonth, 
    bs = "cc", k = 12, by = State) + s(Time) + s(Time, 
    by = State) + State + Weight

Parametric coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -5.600567   1.915070  -2.924  0.00345 ** 
StateSA      2.296414   1.958935   1.172  0.24109    
StateACT     2.722882   1.931200   1.410  0.15856    
StateNT      2.741779   1.936817   1.416  0.15689    
StateTAS     2.840822   1.931547   1.471  0.14136    
StateWA      3.663745   1.926950   1.901  0.05726 .  
StateQLD     4.558119   1.918682   2.376  0.01752 *  
StateNSW     5.180326   1.916782   2.703  0.00688 ** 
Weight       0.024802   0.001211  20.483  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                         edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
s(nMonth)          2.8108887     10  7.518 0.006639 ** 
s(nMonth):StateVIC 0.0001586     10  0.000 0.881803    
s(nMonth):StateSA  0.0042071     10  0.004 0.372360    
s(nMonth):StateACT 2.8087942     10  9.153 0.010985 *  
s(nMonth):StateNT  0.0009192     10  0.001 0.400157    
s(nMonth):StateTAS 2.6050443     10 14.099 0.000401 ***
s(nMonth):StateWA  2.8284593     10  5.670 0.069888 .  
s(nMonth):StateQLD 0.8103377     10  1.202 0.177543    
s(nMonth):StateNSW 0.8037696     10  1.174 0.162019    
s(Time)            4.9716645      9 36.543 3.10e-09 ***
s(Time):StateVIC   3.9042018      9 31.692 2.38e-07 ***
s(Time):StateSA    2.4917897      9 33.675 4.97e-09 ***
s(Time):StateACT   0.0003560      9  0.000 0.669290    
s(Time):StateNT    0.0002071      9  0.000 0.933419    
s(Time):StateTAS   0.5862472      9  1.394 0.096529 .  
s(Time):StateWA    1.9987047      9 11.805 0.000462 ***
s(Time):StateQLD   1.2941229      9  2.433 0.109010    
s(Time):StateNSW   0.9173834      9 10.547 5.58e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  -9.98e+05   Deviance explained = 91.7%
-REML =   1252  Scale est. = 1         n = 2124
```

The model also produces a good looking rootogram.

```
root_nb2 <- rootogram(supply.negbinom, style = "hanging", plot = FALSE)
x11(); autoplot(root_nb2)
```

[image: Plot]

but diagnostic plots produced by `gam.check()` (via `appraise()` from `gratia` package) look average and `gam.check()` also flags all my `Time` related smooth as potentially problematic.

[image: plot2]

```
Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 17 iterations.
Gradient range [-0.000111227,0.0001177008]
(score 1252.014 & scale 1).
eigenvalue range [-0.0001176733,46.7456].
Model rank =  180 / 180 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                         k'      edf k-index p-value    
s(nMonth)          1.00e+01 2.81e+00    0.87    0.15    
s(nMonth):StateVIC 1.00e+01 1.59e-04    0.87    0.13    
s(nMonth):StateSA  1.00e+01 4.21e-03    0.87    0.08 .  
s(nMonth):StateACT 1.00e+01 2.81e+00    0.87    0.10    
s(nMonth):StateNT  1.00e+01 9.19e-04    0.87    0.14    
s(nMonth):StateTAS 1.00e+01 2.61e+00    0.87    0.11    
s(nMonth):StateWA  1.00e+01 2.83e+00    0.87    0.10    
s(nMonth):StateQLD 1.00e+01 8.10e-01    0.87    0.14    
s(nMonth):StateNSW 1.00e+01 8.04e-01    0.87    0.09 .  
s(Time)            9.00e+00 4.97e+00    0.81  <2e-16 ***
s(Time):StateVIC   9.00e+00 3.90e+00    0.81  <2e-16 ***
s(Time):StateSA    9.00e+00 2.49e+00    0.81  <2e-16 ***
s(Time):StateACT   9.00e+00 3.56e-04    0.81  <2e-16 ***
s(Time):StateNT    9.00e+00 2.07e-04    0.81  <2e-16 ***
s(Time):StateTAS   9.00e+00 5.86e-01    0.81  <2e-16 ***
s(Time):StateWA    9.00e+00 2.00e+00    0.81  <2e-16 ***
s(Time):StateQLD   9.00e+00 1.29e+00    0.81  <2e-16 ***
s(Time):StateNSW   9.00e+00 9.17e-01    0.81  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**Q: What are the key diagnostic features to look at here to diagnose an ill fitting model?**

The models adjusted R squared is negative. In models with a gaussian error distribution I believe that this can indicate an over-fitted model. However, I note that the [summary.gam()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.8-36/topics/summary.gam) page suggests that for non-normal error distributions the deviance explained is probably more important, which is this case, the deviance explained is good and quite high. The results of `gam.check()` also do not look good, with the plots looking poor and all the `Time` related smooths being significant with a K-index below 1. However, again, I believe this to be more important for models with a gaussian error distribution; I note that `gam.check()` [suggests that the residuals extracted from the `gam` object are not standardised for the family used](https://rdrr.io/cran/mgcv/man/gam.check.html). Lastly, my model produced a great looking rootogram, which I believe to be important for assessing the fit of count distribution model (good post on interpreting rootograms [here](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/06/07/rootograms/%5C)).